# Finding the probability of a region $|X-Y|$

Tags: probability, geometry, random-variables, density-function

I have a region in a 3-D space with a **density** of 
$$
\
f_{x,y,z}(X,Y,Z) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $ (x,y,z)\in W$}; \\
0 & \text{if $(x,y,z)\notin W$};\\
\end{cases}
\ $$

Being $W$ the set of points inside the pyramid $(0,0,0)$, $(2,0,0)$,$(0,3,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$

Im asked to find $P\{|X-Y|\leq \frac{1}{2}\}$

For doing so I know the point $x=(2,0,0)$ and the line from this point to $(0,3,0)$ which is $y=\frac{-3}{2}x+3$. So and aproach to $|X-Y|$ would be $2 -(\frac{-3}{2}x+3)=\frac{3}{2}x-1$

And then $3 \int_{0}^{1/2} (\frac{3}{2}x-1)dx  $?

Comment: You could use a pile of indicator functions, such as $1_{x \gt 0}$, $1_{y \gt 0}$, $1_{z \gt 0}$, $1_{z \lt 1}$, $1_{y \lt 3-3z}$, $1_{x \lt 2 - 2z - \frac23 y}$ for the original pyramid, and  adding  $1_{x \ge y -\frac12}$ and $1_{x \le y +\frac12}$ for the target.  Then you have triple integrals where the indicator functions turn into ranges of integration.

Comment: I don't understand very well how the indicator functions work. It is the first time i notice them.